# Getting current mouse pointer position in IKImageView

Tags: xcode, cocoa, annotate, ikimageview

I am using IKImageView to display the image.  I need to add a note when releasing the mouse pointer that has shown in below image. How can i get the x and y position when i release the mouse after drawing?

when i click the draw function "[_imageView setCurrentToolMode: IKToolModeAnnotate];" this wil execute.

[image]

Comment: Did you implement this method  -(void) mouseMoved: (NSEvent *) thisEvent in your code?

Comment: @HussainShabbir ya, but that method is not called...